# How does a finite state machine work if it is ambiguous?

Tags: state-machine

The finite state machine in question:-

[image]

If I am at S0, and the input is a, do I repeat to S0 again or do I move onto S1? I don't know how to determine this. Is this kind of FSM even valid?

Which of these input combinations will end in the halting state?

- aaabc
- ccc
- bc
- bbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a NFA (non-deterministic automata).

The words accepted by the automata are:

- **aaabc**
- **bc**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton

Comment: What does the "automate" mean?

Answer (score -1):

August

Only the "aaabc" is valid, the rest are halting as the FSM has "a" as the legitimate S0 entry.